# toggling background of button not working

Tags: android, button

I have created an app that suppose to toggle the button background color on every click. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.flash.light;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button screen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screen);
        Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black);
        screen.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

        screen.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){ 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                Button screen = (Button) findViewById (R.id.screen);
                Drawable background = screen.getResources().getDrawable(screen.getId());
                if(background == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black)){
                    Drawable newBackgroun = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white);
                    screen.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
                }
                if(background == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white)){
                    Drawable newBackgroun = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black);
                    screen.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
                }
            } 
        }); 
    }
```

Click on the button doesn't response. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean isBlack = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // your code

        final Button screen = (Button) findViewById (R.id.screen);
        isBlack = true;
        screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        screen.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){ 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                if (isBlack){ 
                    screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    isBlack = false;
                }
                else{
                    screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    isBlack = true;
                }
            }

        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I belive the problem here is that the resource returned by your

```
getResources().getDrawable(int id)
```

is different everytime you call it. Android just constructs new instance of drawable class instead of returning old one. (At least I belive that there is no caching in this case)

Comparing three different instances with == operator will never return true.

Second thing is an obvious bug in the code:

```
            Button screen = (Button) findViewById (R.id.screen);
            Drawable background = screen.getResources().getDrawable(screen.getId());
            if(background == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black)){
                Drawable newBackgroun = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white);
                screen.setBackgroundDrawable(**newBackground**);
            }
            if(background == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white)){
                Drawable newBackgroun = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black);
                screen.setBackgroundDrawable(**newBackground**);
            }
```

instead of background you should have newBackground there.

Comment: @VladIoffe Updated answer - pasted fixed code snipped. But it still does not fix the problem with different instances I belive. But you can try that first.